# Clarify permute::how() usage for restricting permutations with adonis2 and permutest

Tags: r, permute

I am trying to clarify whether I've structured my permutation restriction correctly based on my project design and application for permutation based hypothesis tests using permute::how() in R. I collected 10 replicate water samples and 8 sites and sequenced by metabarcoding. I would consider samples within sites to be exchangeable units. I would like to construct a restriction that allows free permutation of samples within but not across sites, or I think this means I would like to permutate all samples from a site together (?). I used the online documentation and textbook examples for guidance, but I'm still not sure if I've set up the argument properly for this objective, where permutations=CTRL:

```
CTRL <- how(within = Within(type = "free"), # freely permute samples within sites
            plots = Plots(strata=as.factor(predictor.df$site.name),
                          type="free"), # restrict permutations to site
            nperm=9999,
            observed = TRUE)
```

Unclear if I've specified `within`, `plots`, and `type` correctly. I don't think the blocks argument applies to my experimental design, and I am considering sites to be plots in the context of the function (which may be wrong too). Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A quick follow-up. I used the shuffle() function to explore how CTRL would permute my samples and tested different specifications. The way I've written it, the order of sample reps 1-10 within sites changes for each permutation, and the order of sites 1-8 also changes. Samples within sites are preserved, as far as I can tell. This is what I intended, so I think I figured it out.

Comment: What you permute (and how you do that) depends on i) the model you have fitted, ii) the variable/effect you are trying to test, and iii) the restrictions on exchangeability that need to be accounted for. You have described only iii); please provide information in i) and ii). It would be a rare setting where you'd want to permute both samples and plots.

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson, thanks for the reply! To clarify: I’m using vegan::adonis2() to run a PERMANOVA, and using the same perm restrictions with a follow-up test for dispersion effects using permutest() and for indicator species analysis with indicspecies::multipatt(). Trying to follow the guidance in J. Bakker’s online multivariate stats textbook for analysis design. I am using presence-absence community data from metabarcoding and Jaccard dissimilarity and testing the effects of categorical variables on differences in community composition among sites. My PERMANOVA setup looks like this:

Comment: set.seed(1993)
model <- adonis2(data ~ georegion + geo.province + season + protected.status,
  predictor.df,
  permutations = CTRL,
  method = "jaccard",
  sqrt.dist = FALSE,
  add = FALSE,
  by = "terms",
  na.action = na.fail,
  strata = NULL
)

Comment: There are two levels for each predictors except province, which has 3. Between 1-5 sites constitute groups of these levels. For example, there are 3 central georegion sites and 5 south region sites, so  group comparisons are unbalanced. I would consider replicate samples within sites exchangeable. I tested CTRL where Within(type=”none”), which generates fewer possible permutations than type=”free”, but I get the same statistics for both. I also don't know how to appropriately address the imbalance if that is a huge problem. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions about this analysis setup!